# lazy objects not converted to null in Jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jackson

I'm using Spring 3.1.4 together with jackson-datatype-hibernate 2.2.3 and get my User-Object from JPA beginning from my REST-Service. So now mails is automatically fetched lazy. What I want is a JSON just with the name and mails is simply null.

MyRest Method:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@RequestMapping(
        value="/get/{userId}", 
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces={"application/json","application/xml"}
        )
@ResponseBody
public User getUser(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId){
    User result = userManager.getUser(userId);
    return result;
}
```

minimized User Class:

```
public class User{

    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Mail> mails;
}
```

Custom Jackson Object Mapper:

```
public class CustomJacksonObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

public CustomJacksonObjectMapper() {
    super();
    this.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    this.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    this.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
}
```

}

which is initialized by

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.fabel" })
public class SpringConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport{

 @Bean
  public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        CustomJacksonObjectMapper objectMapper = new CustomJacksonObjectMapper();
    Hibernate4Module hibernate4Module = new Hibernate4Module();
    objectMapper.registerModule(hibernate4Module);
    return objectMapper;
  }

  @Override
  public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new                               MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
   converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper());
   converters.add(converter);
  }
```

}

I orientated my implementation on the german blog http://blog.rasc.ch/?p=2441 and did everything mentioned. 
Any ideas what I can do? 
@JacksonIgnore is no option, because sometimes I need to send lazy objects. Then I would simply use Hibernate.initialize. What am I missing?

Comment: What is it actually serializing it to?

Comment: It just returns Code 500

Comment: Set your logger to DEBUG and check your logs for errors.

Comment: Unfortunately it already is set. The main question is, if I configured the ObjectMapper right and if there is a special option I missed.

Answer (score 0):

this is maybe too late, anyway there is a library that would help you through lazy loading with hiberante which is `jackson-datatype-hibernate4`.

you can do as following to create a `ObjectMapper` object that can load lazy data and serialized it:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Hibernate4Module hibernate4Module = new Hibernate4Module();
hibernate4Module.enable(Hibernate4Module.Feature.SERIALIZE_IDENTIFIER_FOR_LAZY_NOT_LOADED_OBJECTS);
mapper.registerModule(hibernate4Module);
```